# Function matching any head (Example: h_[_,_] := 5)

Tags: function-construction, pattern-matching, head

I want to define a function matching any expression with 2 parameters. For example:

```
_[_, _] := 5
```

I get the following error:

> SetDelayed::nosym: "*[*,_] does not contain a symbol to attach a rule to. "

Expected results are:

```
f[1, 2] = 5
g[3, 4] = 5
```

How to create such a rule?

Comment: Should `Hold[f][1, 2]` also return `5` as well? What is this needed for, exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such a downvalue definition is impossible. The way values work is that a symbol serves as a tag to trigger the pattern matching mechanism. You have no tag. Also note that if you could do this, it would have massive, presumably unintended, consequences. Every head with two arguments that came up anywhere within *Mathematica*'s internal calculations would be replaced by `5`.

But you can do the transformation in a controlled way on expressions you choose to transform:

```
to5[e_] := e /. _[_, _] -> 5
```

Comment: Heaven forbid someone would be foolhardy enough to assign this function to `$Post`...

Comment: @J.M.'stechnicaldifficulties ツ